# Mobicents- Sip Servlets on Tomcat - Disconnecting multi party

Tags: tomcat, mobicents-sip-servlets

I am a newbie at developing SIP applications on SIP-Servlets. I have tried developing multiparty basic SIP connections which is explained below.

1. Received a call from A. (Session-1)
2. Created an Invite to B. (Session-2)
3. Created an Invite to C.(Session-1 in-dialog)

To create an invitation to C I used the code snippet below

```
SipServletRequest invite2C=sipFactory1.createRequest(sipServletRequest.getApplicationSession(),"INVITE",ad1,ad2);
```

I want this invite to be created in Session-3 and to be linked to other 2 sessions. Is there a possible scenario in Sip Servlets to do this? Kindly guide.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is contradictory because you say you want to create INVITE to C in Session 1

"3. Create an Invite to C.(Session-1 in-dialog)"

Then further below you say you want it to be on Session 3 : "I want this invite to be created in Session-3 and to be linked to other 2 sessions"

Can you correct your post to explain which one you need ?

Comment: Thanks Jean for the prompt reply. What I am trying say thru the post is:  INVITE-C is being displayed as in Session-1 in-dialog, which is not my requirement. I am looking for creating the INVITE-C in Session-3.

Comment: Oh I see. Yeah that should be the behavior. Can you share DEBUG logs on https://groups.google.com/group/mobicents-public so we can investigate ? Which version are you using ?